# Flex grid automatic width

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have three griditems in a grid row. 
Two with fixed width. How can i make the third scale automatically to maximize the grid?

I'd like the same functionality as html:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr><td width=50></td>
<td>this scales</td>
</td><td width=50></td></tr></table>
```

Regards
Anders

Comment: Have you tried applying a width of 100% to the column you want to expand automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code snippet can help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application layout="absolute" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Grid bottom="0" left="0" right="0" top="0">
        <mx:GridRow width="100%">
            <mx:GridItem width="50">
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem width="50">
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem width="100%">
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem width="50">
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
        <mx:GridRow width="100%">
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
            <mx:GridItem>
                <mx:Button label="Test" width="100%" />
            </mx:GridItem>
        </mx:GridRow>
    </mx:Grid>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I've made a suggestion the question isn't about `Grid` in 4.5 :)